# C++ Templates with pointer to member function by signature and type

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, function-pointers, language-lawyer

The code below works fine but I can't figure out based what points of the C++ standard it should be valid.

```
template< class C, class signature >
void f(signature C::*ptr) { }
```

When `C = A` and `signature = void(float, int)`, the function f will be

```
void f(void(A::*ptr)(float, int))
```

Based on which parts of the standard, does the template apply to the latter?

Comment: @Daniel Frey yes. I know that all works. I ask: why is that works? Where can I read in the C++ standart that such thing is proper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best go through this one by one. To avoid ambiguities, I'll use different template argument names in the example

```
template<class C, class signature> void f(signature C::*ptr) {}
```

All quotes refer to the latest working draft of the C++14 standard.

First we need to understand, how the template parameters are treated.

> **[temp.param]/3** A type-parameter whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis defines
>   its identifier to be a typedef-name

So your template definition has two parameters `T` and the signature. When using `signature` in the template body, it is therefore equivalent to the typedef

```
typedef void signature(float, int);
```

This typedef may be used to declare a function pointer parameter, as in your example:

> **[dcl.fct]/12** A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall
>   not be used to define a function

In the parameters of the template function, you write `signature T::*ptr`, let's see what the standard says about member pointers:

> **[dcl.mptr]/1** In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> ```
> nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seq_opt cv-qualifier-seq_opt D1
> ```
>
> and the *nested-name-specifier* denotes a class, and the type of the
>   identifier in the declaration `T D1` is *derived-declarator-type-list
>   T*, then the type of the identifier of `D` is
>   *derived-declarator-type-list cv-qualifier-seq pointer to member of class nested-name-specifier of type T*.

In our example, `T` is `signature`, the function typedef, and `D` is `C::*ptr`.

This explains what types the compiler will deduce for the example

```
void f(void(A::*ptr)(float, int));
```